# Visual Studio 2010 Prof: Solution Explorer not showing files from Import .targets

Tags: visual-studio-2010, import, partial, csproj, solution-explorer

Since i have many configurations for single project i wanted to clean .csproj little bit.
I moved all config definitions to single files with Conditional ItemGroup and imported them in .csproj with:

```
<Import Project="conf/file.targets">
```

Everything seems fine except one thing, in solution explorer i dont see files which are defined in .targets, but project compiles without any problems. Is it bug, or normal behavior? How can i see files that are imported from .targets? (ie. SomeFile and SomeFile2.)
Example test.targets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'TestConfig|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\TestConfig\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='TestConfig' ">
    <Compile Include="SomeFile.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SomeFile2.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Everything was visible in Solution Explroer when it was defined in .csproj.

PS. i searched in google and stackoverflow, but didn't found any usefull information.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Andy no, there was no solution for this (at least for VS 2010), Didn't try in never versions of Visual Studio

Comment: @Andy i checked in VS 2015 Pro and it behaves exactly the same as VS2010, so i don't have workaround for this.

Comment: Related, but not quite a duplicate: [Moving compile items in msbuild into a separate file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501317/moving-compile-items-in-msbuild-into-a-separate-file)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's use of MSBuild files is subset of what MSBuild is capable of.

In particular VS structures project files in a way it can understand, it is quite possible to have a valid MSBuild file that is not a valid VS project file. If you want to use VS to manage project content you need to stick to the subset of MSBuild that VS uses and understands.

Comment: so is there any other way to have clean managabale .csproj file, 35-40 configs, in each 5-10 conditional files?

Comment: @cichy: I suspect there isn't. You might be better looking at macros/extensions to make managing groups of configurations (bulk parameter setting) easier.