# Moving compile items in msbuild into a separate file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

This is probably a FAQ, but we weren't able to find a solution even after a lot of searching.

We have a number of msbuild files that all operate on the same set of source files. (It's not particularly relevant but they compile to completely different platforms.) To make managing these a little simpler, we'd like to move the `<Compile>` source file names to a separate file and reference that from all the msbuild files.

We tried cutting the `<ItemGroup>` containing the `<Compile>` items and pasting it into a new file, and surrounding it with

`<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="3.5"` `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`

and then referencing that file from the original with

`<Import Project="Common.files.csproj" />`

but that does not work - the solution opens (with a warning since we hacked the default config), but no items appear in the Solution Explorer.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you select "Show all Files"?

Comment: @mellamokb: that shouldn't matter - Show All Files only toggles showing what's on disk. I tried it as well just to be sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tried with Visual Studio 2010:

1) Create your external .proj (or .target) file and add your files (I used a different item name but that shouldn't matter)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ExternalCompile Include="Program.cs" />
        <ExternalCompile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

2) Import your external .proj file **at the top of your Visual Studio project file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <Import Project="MyExternalSources.proj" />
   <PropertyGroup>
   ...
```

and modify the `Compile` ItemGroup like this:

```
...
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="@(ExternalCompile)" />
</ItemGroup>
...
```

---

**Warning:** You'll have to add new items/files to your external .proj file - all items/files added from within Visual Studio will end up like this:

```
...
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="@(ExternalCompile)" />
    <Compile Include="MyNewClass.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
...
```

Comment: Excellent, that works. Yes, it's a pity to have to add items by hand, but they can be added as usual and then moved to the external file prior to checking in.

Comment: I have tried the same technique with <Content /> but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know of way to import a 'default' set of content, e.g. when working with an existing OSS complied web application.

Comment: @uniquelau I just tried and expirienced a problem when files are located outside the "main" project folder. As soon as I moved the "static" content to the project folder it worked the same with a `Content` ItemGroup. My solution is really only a workaround and shows how you can tweak VS project files. Maybe a custom post-build task could handle moving static content in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen "include" files work with MSBuild.  Obviously Targets files work this way, but I haven't seen a partial msbuild file included in another.  COuld you use a method such as illustrated in this?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171454(VS.80).aspx

Using wildcards is how I've addressed this in the past.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still holding out for a solution. This may be a last resort if all else fails, but it's not optimal.

Comment: you could also use the CreateItem task coupled with your own custom file parsing to add items to the Compile ItemGroup during a BeforeBuild target... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2y3e43x.aspx