# How do I add a file to a C# project with an Import statement in the csproj?

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I'm trying to write a small `.targets` file to include our log4net bits in all our projects.

Thus I wrote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>    
        <Compile Include="logging\Log4Net.cs" />
        <Compile Include="logging\SXmlLayout.cs" />
        <None Include="logging\default.log4net">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Include="logging\SXmlLayout.xsd">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None> 
    <Reference Include="log4net">
        <HintPath>..\log4net\net45\log4net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
 </Project>
```

And in the main project I added this just after the csharp targets file:

```
  ...oft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\logging\sis.logging.targets" />
```

Now, if I deliberately misspell the filename it errors. So it's reading the file OK.

the log4net DLL is getting references correctly, so it's definitely doing something.

BUT, none of the files get included in the project.

Is there something wrong with that file? Can this even work?

Comment: The IDE doesn't look in imported files to see if they contain any items.  You probably ought to consider make your own project template.  File + Export Template.

Comment: There was a solution, found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501317/moving-compile-items-in-msbuild-into-a-separate-file useful for automatically adding the assembly attribute to make log4net go